# How can I suppress the headers from CLI CURL's output of request

Tags: rest, curl, command-line-interface

There's plenty of info on how to prevent curl from showing header information when doing a request for the PHP version, but seemingly nothing for the CLI version.

my request is in the form

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -H 'X-Accept: application/json' -H '-d '{"somedata":"12ihiuhihihed994f63dbef6b012b"}' https://myurl.com/v3/oauth/request
```

Which works, but returns this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 20:42:11 GMT
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND UNI COM NAV INT STA PRE"
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Amazon)
Status: 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20
Content-Length: 54
Connection: keep-alive

{"code":"jkhjhhjhaa","state":null}
```

when all I really want is this:

```
{"code":"jkhjhhjhaa","state":null}
```

Comment: Although it's enough to remove the -i option to achieve what you want, the option -D also causes the header to be in the output.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Simply remove the `-i` switch from your `curl` command.

```
man curl
```

said :

> -i, --include
>   (HTTP) Include the HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header includes things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and more...

Comment: In my curl command -i switch is not there, but still it is printing headers.

Answer (score 26):

In order to suppress output from CURL CLI --silent option can be used. It perfectly works when curl output is piped as well.

```
-s, --silent        Silent mode (don't output anything)
```

Answer (score 3):

In case this isn't obvious, also don't use the -v (verbose) switch with -s (silent)